# Using protocol to update UIViewController when push notification received?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, push-notification, appdelegate

Is this a proper way to notify a UIViewController after receiving a push notification in AppDelegate? The UIViewController needs to refresh its contents after getting a push notification. New to Swift so want to confirm this is a valid approach in Swift.

AppDelegate:

```
protocol PushNotificationDelegate : class {
    func didReceivePushNotification()
}


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var pushDelegates = [PushNotificationDelegate]()

    ...

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }

        // Notify delegates
        for delegate in pushDelegates {
            delegate.didReceivePushNotification()
        }
    }


    func addPushNotificationDelegate(newDelegate: PushNotificationDelegate) {
        if (pushDelegates.indexOf{$0 === newDelegate} == nil) {
            pushDelegates.append(newDelegate)
        }
    }
}
```

UIViewController:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, PushNotificationDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        // Get notified when push notifications come in
        if let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.addPushNotificationDelegate(self)
        }
    }


   func didReceivePushNotification() {

   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all looks well and idiomatic Swift. There is one thing to keep in mind is that you need to ensure to remove the view controller from the delegate list that you maintain in AppDelegate, when it is being dismissed. Otherwise, your view controller will not get removed from memory.  You can implement that code in HomeViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear(animated:Bool){
   [super viewWillDisappear]
//Remove 'self' from the delegate array maintained in AppDelegate.
}
```

Comment: OK thanks. But if HomeViewController is a root controller, it's not necessary to remove it from the delegate list right?

Comment: Yes, in that case, you don't need to. But for others you need to.